# Checking for custom view mode inside twig template!

Tags: theming, 8

I am using {% if teaser %} .... {% endif %} To change structure of content type according to its view mode.

But it looks like I cannot check for custom view modes created using Drupal 8, Such as:

```
{% if medium_teaser %}
  <div id="product-teaser">
     {{ content.field_image }}
     <a class="buy-now-btn" href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': 
     node.id}) }}">Buy now</a>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to check for custom view modes in twig templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that's the [node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.4.x), you have a `view_mode` variable available:

```
{% if view_mode == 'foo' %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: instead of 'foo' Should i write the machine name of the view mode ???! like : "medium_teaser"

Comment: Yes, that's correct